# Moto g 2nd gen, lollipop bootloader unlock issue

Tags: rooting, root-access, fastboot, motorola-moto-g, superuser

I have just bought Moto G 2nd generation smart phone with 16 gb internal memory. To root device, I tried to unlock bootloader. But it didn't go smooth. When I hit command `fastboot oem unlock <key>`, I got success message with status `Device unlocked. Status 3`.

But what the heck this `status 3`?. I am not getting any info about this.

Google search is showing that, at time of unlocking bootloader, few messages are shown like `unlocked` then `restarted` and device restarts. But this didn't happen with me. So I manually restarted my device for custom recovery. And flashed rom using `TWRP2.7.1.1-titan-motog-2014`. This command also showed me success message. Before this I copied `UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.02.zip` in device.

But after restarting and hitting recovery, device is not showing any thing and just black screen and then turning off.

Apart from this device is working fine, with normal boot.

P.S. `RootChecker` is showing that `Root access is not properly installed on this device`.

So what is the way out to root the device again properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Device Unlocked. Status 3
```

This means that your device has it's bootloader unlocked. So, all you have to do is just reflash the latest `Update Superuser V___.zip`. And,you have the recovery installed which should make this a easy process.

Hope this works. Good luck!